# Render Livewire Component Multiple Times Causes Styling Issue

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I am trying to render my livewire component everytime "[[[newsletter]]]" is within the content. I render the component with this code:

```
public function handle(string $content, Closure $next)
    {
        $replacers = View::make('components.newsletter.investing-intel')->toHtml();

        $content = str_replace('[[[newsletter]]]', "$replacers", $content);

        return $next($content);
    }
```

Within my investing-intel.blade.php I have more code but I'll just show how I render the livewire component:

```
<livewire:subscriber-form dark-mode="0" />
```

I then have the following for my subscriber-form.blade.php:

```
<div>
    @if(!$subscribed)
        <form wire:submit.prevent="submit" class="w-full max-w-md lg:col-span-5 lg:pt-2" x-data="{ darkMode: {{ (int) $darkMode  }} }">
            <x-honeypot livewire-model="extraFields" />
            <div class="flex gap-x-4">
                <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
                <input wire:model="email" id="email" name="email" type="email" autocomplete="email"
                       :class="{'text-white bg-white/5 placeholder:text-white ring-white/10 focus:ring-brand-500': darkMode, 'text-gray-900 ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-brand-600': !darkMode }"
                       class="min-w-0 flex-auto rounded-md border-0 px-3.5 py-2 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
                       placeholder="Enter your email">
                <button type="submit"
                        :class="{'bg-brand-600 hover:bg-brand-700 focus-visible:outline-brand-500': darkMode, 'bg-brand-600 hover:bg-brand-500 focus-visible:outline-brand-600': !darkMode }"
                        class="flex-none rounded-md py-2.5 px-3.5 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 ">Subscribe</button>
            </div>
            @error('email')
                <span class="text-red-500 text-xs italic">{{ $message }}</span>
            @enderror
            <p :class="{'text-white': darkMode, 'text-gray-900': !darkMode }"
               class="mt-4 text-sm leading-6">
                We care about your data. Read our <a href="{{ url('/privacy') }}" :class="{'text-brand-600 hover:text-brand-500 font-semibold': darkMode, 'text-brand-600 hover:text-brand-500': !darkMode }" class="font-semibold">privacy&nbsp;policy</a>.
            </p>
        </form>
    @else
        <div class="font-medium lg:col-span-5 lg:pt-2 max-w-md text-2xl text-center w-full">
            <span>You are subscribed!</span>
        </div>
    @endif
</div>
```

Within my content, I have 3 of "[[[newsletter]]]" that are then replaced with the livewire component, the issue is that the styling for the subscriber form works fine for the first component that is rendered, but no styling is applied for any other component other than the first.

Is rendering the component like this the problem?

```
<livewire:subscriber-form dark-mode="0" />
```

Because if I don't render the code like above and just use all the code from within the subscriber-form.blade.php instead of "<livewire:subscriber-form dark-mode="0" />", then the styling works fine for all components.

If I try applying a unique id to each livewire component that is rendered like so:

```
private static $counter = 0;

    public function handle(string $content, Closure $next)
    {
        $count = substr_count($content, '[[[newsletter]]]');

        self::$counter += $count;

        $keys = range(self::$counter - $count + 1, self::$counter);

        preg_match_all('/\[\[\[newsletter\]\]\]/', $content, $matches);

        foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
            $wireKey = array_shift($keys);

            $replacers = View::make('components.newsletter.investing-intel', ['wireKey' => $wireKey])->toHtml();

            $content = preg_replace('/\[\[\[newsletter\]\]\]/', $replacers, $content, 1);
        }

        return $next($content);
    }
```

and this in the investing-intel.blade.php:

```
<h1>{{ $wireKey }}</h1>
<livewire:subscriber-form wire:key="{{ $wireKey }}" dark-mode="0" />
```

A unique id is successfully applied to the 2 [[[newsletter]]] that are found. ID "1" and "2" are applied. With this solution, not even the first rendered component has styling, none of them do.

Comment: try add all in a `<div>`  like :`<div>
    <h1>{{ $wireKey }}</h1>
    <livewire:subscriber-form wire:key="{{ $wireKey }}" dark-mode="0" />
</div>
`

Comment: No luck with trying that @fransico. Just the same result with no styling being applied

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rendering livewire component like this?

```
public function handle(string $content, Closure $next)
{
    $replacers = '<livewire:subscriber-form dark-mode="0" />';

    $content = str_replace('[[[newsletter]]]', $replacers, $content);

    return $next($content);
}
```

But keep in mind when doing this you will also need to use

```
{!! $content !!}
```

Instead of

```
{{ $content }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @afcyy, however, I already do this and it doesn't fix the styling issue.

Comment: Try setting unique wire:key for $replacers. something like - 
`"<livewire:subscriber-form wire:key='item-{$item->id}' dark-mode='0'/>"`

Comment: I've tried applying a key previously and it didn't seem to help either. I've updated the question and added what I attempted at the bottom of the question @afcyy

Comment: Is there no errors in the console at all?

One more idea I have it to try this

`str_replace('[[[newsletter]]]', Livewire::mount("subscriber-form", ["darkmode" => 0]);, $content);`

Comment: Just tried your solution and it's the same result for that also. I have "livewire.js?id=5eee0fac:4492 Uncaught Component already registered" in my console

Comment: Could you try setting wire:key="{{ \Str::uuid() }}" and then check the console if you are still getting the same error or something else? also, are you trying to replace newsletter with your livewire component from the middleware?